# Animation-flll-mode forwards to working

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have read a ton of previous posts on this and nothing suggested is working so I'm wondering if I am missing something obvious or this can't be done without JS.

I have the following animation but even with the 'forwards' fill mode, the slide still jumps back to its original position just before the following slide loads. Any help appreciated, thanks. (vendor prefixes removed for brevity).

There is no html as I am modifying part of a theme.

```
.slider {
overflow:hidden ;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
}

.slide1::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw + 120px);
height: calc(100vh + 150px);
z-index: 1;
background: url(image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
left:0;
top:-20vh;
animation:move 6s ease forwards;
}

.slide2::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw + 120px);
height: calc(100vh + 150px);
z-index: 1;
background: url(image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
left:-150px;
top:-20vh;
animation:movesecond 6s ease forwards;
}

.slide3::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw + 120px);
height: calc(100vh + 150px);
z-index: 1;
background: url(image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
left:0;
top:-20vh;
animation:movethird 6s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
from {
transform: scale(1);
}
to {
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) translate(-150px, -120px);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes movesecond { 
from {
transform: scale(1);
  }
to {
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) translate(150px, 120px);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes movethird { 
from {
transform: scale(1);
}
to {
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) translate(-150px, -120px);
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of using of using `from` and `to`. You can use percents and define exactly how you want the slides to be shown

Comment: Yes I understand that Roysh thank you, will that however fix the problem of the image reverting to its original position?

Comment: I'm really not sure. If you can post a fiddle of just an example of what you need. I might solve your problem